# Backbone.js Collections View forEach doesn't work

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I am trying to use collections to list my data coming from my api. 
But the problem is, when I use forEach, the function that I called (addOne) doesn't run.

There is also something I suspect working wrong. Should my collection save the returning JSON under the models like that?

```
Object -> models -> 0 -> attributes -> ...
```

My View:

```
s.Views.Fs = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: "",
    template: _.template("<%= name %>"),
    initialize: function() {

    },
    render: function() {
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
    },
    addOne: function(f) {
        alert("a");
        var fV = new s.Views.PF({model: f});
        this.$el.append(fV.render().el);
    }
});
```

My Collection:

```
s.Collections.FL = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "api/fs/",
    model: s.Models.F,
});
```

My Model:

```
s.Models.F = Backbone.Model.extend( {
    urlRoot: 'api/fs/',
    defaults: {
        ...
    },
    ...
    parse: function(response) {
            return response;
    },
});
```

My Route (And App):

```
var sApp = new (Backbone.Router.extend({
    f_a: function() {
        this.fL= new s.Collections.FL();
        this.fLV= new s.Views.Fs({collection: this.fL});
        this.fL.fetch();
        this.fLV.render();
    },
});
```

Comment: `fetch` is an AJAX call, you have to listen for events or add a `success` handler to know when it gets some data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listening for events is made by `this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);` under collection's view. Here is tested code's summary (Thanks for the tip 'mu is too short'):

**VIEW**

```
s.Views.Fs = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: "",
    template: _.template("<%= name %>"),
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
        this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
    },
    addOne: function(f) {
        var fV = new s.Views.PF({model: f});
        fV.render();
        this.$el.append(fV.el);
    }
});
```

**COLLECTION**

```
s.Collections.FL = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "api/fs/",
    model: s.Models.F,
});
```

**MODEL**

```
s.Models.F = Backbone.Model.extend( {
    urlRoot: 'api/fs/',
    // No need to parse here.
});
```

**ROUTER**

```
var sApp = new (Backbone.Router.extend({
    f_a: function() {
        this.fL= new s.Collections.FL();
        this.fLV= new s.Views.Fs({collection: this.fL});
        this.fLV.render();
        $("#content").html(this.fLV.el);
        this.fL.fetch();
    },
});
```